# I am attempting to output a pattern of numbers that takes an input and descends then ascends back up to the original number one digit at a time

Tags: javascript, recursion, design-patterns, numbers, cascade

I am trying to write a problem that outputs a similar pattern to this using recursion.

```
cascade(12345) //should print

12345
1234
123
12
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I figured out how to do the descending part but I am stuck on how to ascend back up! This is what I have so far...

```
function cascade(number) {
  let strNum = number.toString()
  let numLength = strNum.length;
  let lengthTracker = numLength
  let hasHit1 = false;
  console.log(strNum)
  if (lengthTracker > 1 && hasHit1 === false) { 
    strNum = strNum.substring(0, strNum.length - 1);
    lengthTracker--;
    return cascade(strNum)
  } else {
    return strNum;
  }
}

cascade(143)
```

this successfully outputs

```
'143'
'14'
'1'
```

How would I add the numbers back onto it one by one afterward?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Another (recursive) approach by using a string.

```js
function cascade(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    console.log(s);
    if (s.length === 1) return; // exit condition
    cascade(s.slice(0, -1));
    console.log(s);
}

cascade(12345);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That is really cool how it console logs them all at the end after it exits each recursive case... I don't know how you people do this stuff! I would've never thought of doing that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**`RECURSIVE APPROACH`**

```js
function cascade(n) {
  if (n === 0) return;
  const remain = Math.floor(n / 10);

  console.log(n);
  String(remain).length !== 1 ? cascade(remain) : console.log(remain);
  console.log(n);
}

cascade(12345);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**`ITERATIVE APPROACH ⏯`**

```js
function cascade(n) {
  const lasts = [];
  while (n) {
    lasts.push(n);
    console.log(n);
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  lasts.length--;
  while (lasts.length) console.log(lasts.pop());
}

cascade(12345);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursion will return these values, leaving you to log them in a separate step.  It might look like this:

```js
const cascade = (n) =>
  n < 10 ? [n] : [n, ... cascade ((n - n % 10) / 10), n]

for (let n of cascade (12345)) console .log (n)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note the separate line to print the result, since the function returns an array such as

```js
[12345, 1234, 123, 12, 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345]
```

The little bit of math in the argument to the recursive call to `cascade` calculates the new number when we strip off the last digit and divide by ten.  We could do this in different ways replacing the function body with:

```js
  n < 10 ? [n] : [n, ... cascade (Math .floor (n / 10)), n]
```

or the slightly more obscure, but shorter

```js
  n < 10 ? [n] : [n, ... cascade (~~ (n / 10)), n]
```

Comment: Well, it works! Thank you for providing me with something to mull over! I will probably have to do this step-by-step to figure it out lol. I appreciate you taking the time to help! I've never seen the ~ used like that before. I will have to research it!

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to some of the other approaches but for what I needed it for, I had to change it up a bit. Hope this helps someone even if this comes a bit late.

```js
cascade(111);

function cascade(number) {
        if(number>9) {
          let newNumber =Math.floor(number/10);
          console.log(number);
          cascade(newNumber);
        };
          console.log(number);
        };
```

```html
<p>check console for results</p>
```